# Wrong code in Live Agent - Custom Chat Page?

Tags: liveagent

I came along with another issue on Live Agent this morning:

Now when I test the button, it loads the proper page but I came along a new message stating something like: "Chat window can be run only through the button - You do not have direct access to it." I got the code from the default chat window by doing a "code inspection" with Safari because I wanted to keep the translations in polish that Salesforce generated. I just copied it to the custom page I created and off course it doesn't work :(

This is the screenshot of the error:

[image: Error Message]

Of course, I did not wanted that Salesforce layout and I guess it's not going to show up when the error will be fixed.

This is the code from the page:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzDrP_xkkm29eUhsMEZiTkFoRXc/view?usp=sharing

This second code works but same layout issue:

[image: Chat Page]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzDrP_xkkm29Z2d1NGNtOEFtYWM/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for your help!

Niko.

Comment: I corrected the layout issue adding the following APEX line: <apex:page showHeader="false"> but still can't find the line that shows the "You do not have direct access to it" error.

Comment: I think you post the code here, some people (like me) don't have access to those dropbox links.

Comment: @PepeFloyd did you tried to copy/paste it? because I made the link public so there is no reasons it doesn't work... I added them also on Google Drive now.

Comment: @PepeFloyd any idea on where this code gets wrong?

Comment: I can't see your code, my corporate network has blocked dropbox and google drive. It will be better if you post the actual code in the question itself.

Comment: I'd like to but its a complete mess! All the HTML and spaces makes it look like hell, it's completely unreadable. @PepeFloyd

Comment: what about using http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: 1st code: http://jsfiddle.net/du84gq81/

Comment: 2nd code: http://jsfiddle.net/ogww8c6t/ @PepeFloyd

Comment: Maybe you know where I can get the original Live Agent chat window code from salesforce so I can write a cleaner code and play with those:    var labels = {
        AGENTS_UNAVAILABLE:...

Comment: Please tell me that you see where the code is wrong and why I get this "You do not have direct access to it" error message :(

Comment: I can't understand what you have pasted there, also the Polish text is confusing to a non Polish speaker. You need to simplify your code and post here your code button and your custom window button, not the resulting HTML.

Comment: This is the HTML code generated by the Live Agent when I didn't chose "Custom Chat Page" and I got from the default chat window through my browser inspector and pasted it in the " Develop/Page/new" menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to call the chat window page directly, this is not allowed.

You need to create a custom chat window page as per the instructions in the Live Agent Developer guide, once you have created that page, go to:

Setup > Live Agent > Chat Buttons > Yourbutton (Edit) > Custom Chat Page (Select your new page here) > Save

Then launch the start as usual using the button code.

Sample Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">
<style>
body { overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0 }
#waitingMessage { height: 100%; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; display: none; }
#liveAgentClientChat.liveAgentStateWaiting #waitingMessage { display: table; }
#liveAgentSaveButton, #liveAgentEndButton { z-index: 2; }
.liveAgentChatInput {
    height: 25px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 4px;
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 99%;
}
.liveAgentSendButton {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 31px;
    padding: 0 0 3px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -67px;
}
#liveAgentChatLog {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
<div style="top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; position: absolute;">
<liveAgent:clientchat >
    <liveAgent:clientChatSaveButton label="Save Chat" />
    <liveAgent:clientChatEndButton label="End Chat" />
    <div style="top: 25px; left: 5px; right: 5px; bottom: 5px; position: absolute; z-index: 0;">
    <liveAgent:clientChatAlertMessage />
    <liveAgent:clientChatStatusMessage />
    <table id="waitingMessage" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Please wait while you are connected to an available agent.</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 41px; left: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; word-wrap: break-word; z-index: 0;">
    <liveAgent:clientChatLog />
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; height: auto; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; margin-right: 67px;">
        <liveagent:clientChatInput /><liveAgent:clientChatSendButton label="Send"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</liveAgent:clientchat>
</div>
</apex:page>
```